# Timestamp Comparators

Tags: mysql, time, comparison

I'm hoping that someone can help with a MySQL query that doesn't seem to be doing exactly what I need it to do.

Client has asked that I make an improvement to their update system for the landing page of the website.  Currently the update system allows them to provide a quick `2` line entry on any recent changes to the site. They do this be entering data into an HTML form and loading the data into a MySQL db.

Currently this system uses only a 'created' column which is a `TIMESTAMP` set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  I've added a column to the table called postdate.  Postdate is a null friendly `TIMESTAMP` with values set via `PHP` and `HTML`.

So far this is all fairly straightforward (and specific to my project). Here's where it gets weird for me:

Given table spec as:

```
CREATE TABLE `updates` (
  `update` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `gallery` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `covers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calendar` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`update`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

why should the query:

```
select updates.name, updates.comment, updates.status, updates.gallery, updates.website, 
                    updates.covers, updates.resume, updates.calendar, 
                    ifnull(postdate, updates.created) as `created`
                from angela.updates
                where updates.status = 1
                and updates.created <= now()
                order by `updates`.`created` desc
        limit 15;
```

Return the following timestamp order:

```
2012-10-15 00:00:00
2013-12-25 00:00:00
2012-12-25 00:00:00
2013-02-01 00:00:00
2013-01-20 13:48:48
2013-01-20 13:36:44
2013-01-20 12:59:57
2013-01-20 12:56:35
2013-01-20 12:49:20
2012-10-29 11:00:12
2012-10-24 14:10:13
2012-08-14 23:53:53
2012-08-14 23:53:18
2012-08-14 23:50:34
2012-08-14 23:50:08
```

Note that rows without a specific time are pulled from the Postdate column while values with a specific time value are pulled from the Created column.

There must be some sort of subtlety to MySQL time comparisons that I'm just not catching on to here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,  I'm giving away Internets for this one.

Comment: What is not making sense to you?  You're ordering the results by `updates.created` but, for those records that have a `postdate` value, are returning that instead.  One would therefore not necessarily expect to see an order in the resultset.

Comment: Ah, I'd expected that because I was aliasing the column the newly aliased column containing the interlaced values would be used for sorting.  I'll review that and see if altering the naming schema addresses the issue.

I see the gap now, removing the `updates`.  portion of the column name resolved it to the query specific version.  

Now to make sure this doesn't creating naming clashes when I add the joins.

I present you with one internet.  Thank you for your help.